# Can't iframe some pages of my website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

Hello I am trying to iframe this element https://allnepaliconverter.com/ok/demo_iframe.html but they keyboard doesn't seem to be iframed .

html code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Virtual Keyboard</title>


<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="vk_iframe.js?vk_skin=goldie&vk_layout=IN Devanagari" ></script>

 </head>
 <body>
     <form action="no.cgi" method="get"><strong>
     <p style="color: red;font-family: sans-serif;"> Enter From The Keyboard Below Using Mouse Or Your Hardware Keyboard Device </p></strong>

     <textarea id="text" cols="72" rows="10" wrap="soft" onfocus="IFrameVirtualKeyboard.attachInput(this)"></textarea>

       <div id="td"></div>
       <body  onload="IFrameVirtualKeyboard.toggle('text','td'); return false;" >

</form>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well where is the test page where it is in an iframe?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your console, you should see :

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://allnepaliconverter.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

This explains why the keyboard does not print. 
Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) for full explanation and possible workarounds.

Comment: One possible workaround would be to reproduce the page on your site : get the scripts, reproduce the html...

Answer (score 0):

May be keyboard is iframe loaded by javascript from same origin. Browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.